# Barplots and other graphics not displaying in terminal (Debian and R)

Tags: linux, r, graphics, terminal, debian

I am using debian, and installed R using the following command:

```
apt-get install r-recommended
```

I then tested out whether it worked by using R to run

```
barplot(1:100)
```

This gave no errors, but provided no output.

Non graphical R commands work, but anything that should display a graphic seems to be ignored. No errors, no warnings, no output at all.

Am I missing a critical library?

Comment: Did you try library(graphics)? Also did you check to see if R was creating pdfs or ps files in the working directory containing the plots (this is what it does when the OS does not have a windowing system installed).

Comment: Does `x11()` create an empty graphics device? (if so, do subsequent plot commands output to that device?)

Comment: when I run x11(), a '>' symbol is produced on a new line. No graphics run.

Comment: >Did you try library(graphics)?
No, what is this?

>did you check to see if R was creating pdfs?

THIS IS WHAT WAS HAPPENING! THANK YOU SO MUCH. Is it possible to make them appear inline?

Comment: Plots will never display inline (in the R console), but the standard behaviour when you call `plot` (as long as you don't already have an active device, e.g. `pdf`, that is in use) is for a new window to be created and for the plot to appear there. If there _is_ an active plotting device, you can end it with `dev.off()`.

Answer (score 2):

Type in x11() and hit enter.  This should open up a graphics window.  Then if you do plot(1:100) you should see a graph.

Answer (score 1):

You can write any plot to the server using the following:

```
png('path/for_my_image/my_image.png', width=6, height=6, units='in', res=300)
dev.off()
```

Choose your height and width as needed.

Then just go find your image through either FTP or by downloading to your local directory via scp.